# How do I find a ghostwriter for a series of books?

Tags: fiction, novel, collaboration, ghostwriter

Where do I find ghost writers? It's for a series I am developing for the Kindle singles series, also to be combined and sold as novels. Word count will be 5k - 20k  - I am interested in splitting revenue on an ongoing basis instead of a single payout.

Is there a market place for this type of work?

Comment: I think before this question can be answered fully there are a number of point's that need to be specified. Most importantly (to some writers), do you have any existing experience and a portfolio of your works? If not then you may have difficulty finding a writer that will essentially write a book for you without some sort of down-payment. Secondly (and more important to me) what sort of books are you intent on developing - I don't think there are many writers out there prepared to write something they themselves wouldn't enjoy reading.

Comment: For you to be able to get a ghostwriter interested in revenue sharing, you must first be able to convince them that there will be revenue to share.

Comment: What are you going to bring to the table, to justify your split of the revenue?  Are you going to be doing much of the writing yourself?  If not, exactly what would you contribute to be as valuable as the person doing the actual work?

Answer (score 6):

Based on all the info in your question: almost nowhere.  You aren't going to get somebody to write books based on your ideas/guidance, with you listed as the main (or only) author [definition of ghostwriter], unless you are famous or have deep pockets (i.e., hefty payment up-front).  The lone exception might be the person who posted a question on here about how he loves to write but can't come up with ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There are countless ghostwriting services easily found through a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ghostwriting%20service). Vary the search terms a bit until you find what you like (e.g. add "fiction" to exclude academic ghostwriters).

But these are people earning a living and expecting pay. [Asking anyone to work for free is insulting.](https://www.boredpanda.com/artists-work-for-free-ryan-estrada-emmie-tsumura/)